# Issue storing date c++

Tags: c++, date, scanf

I have a class, Student.
It contains a private member 'dob'
I want to set the string dob as a proper date.
I'm supposed to validate the input, and I have attempted to use scanf for this, but I am not sure why my output is off.

```
void Student::getBday(){
    int mm, dd, yyyy;
    printf("Date of Birth?\n");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &mm, &dd, &yyyy);
    dob = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
}
```

Here's my print function:

```
void Student::printStudent(){
    cout.flush();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Student: " << lastName << ", " << firstName << endl;
    cout << "Student ID: " << ID << endl;
    cout << "Gender: " << gender << endl;
    cout << "Status: " << status << endl;
    cout << "Date of Birth: " << dob << endl;
    cout << "GPA: " << gpa << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

My output:

```
LastName?
Bar
FirstName?
Foo
Gender?
M
Status?
Freshman
Date of Birth?
12/21/2012
GPA?
3.5
ID?
12345678
12345678

Student: Bar, Foo
Student ID: 12345678
Gender: M
Status: Freshman
Date of Birth: [
GPA: 3.5

Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Edit:**

Finally got it working. Thank you all that helped. I selected that answer because it helped me convert, but everyone helped me understand my concatenation issue.

Comment: For the 28th of September, 2015, the value of `mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy` is 2146. You probably want to convert your numbers to strings after they've been validated.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm confused, sorry. What would I need to do to store that date as mm/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but please consider reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 and storing / prompting for dates in the internationally standardised format (yyyy-mm-dd), not the confusing mm/dd/yyyy (or even dd/mm/yyyy) format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the way you are using scanf that's causing the issue.

It should be more something like

```
...
printf ("Date of Birth?");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &mm, &dd, &yyyy); 
...
```

**Edit**

Here is an example of sprinf( ... )

```
...
int mm,dd,yyyy;
char dob [50];
printf ("Date of Birth?");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &mm, &dd, &yyyy); 
sprintf (dob, "%d/%d/%d", mm, dd, yyyy);
...
```

Comment: I just modified it to say printf("Date of Birth?\n"); but I still do not get the full string displayed when I try to print it.

Comment: But you enter the date as "121212", your function expects exactly "12/12/12". Also, how is "dob" defined? normally you should use sprinf( ,... ) to get string from numbers.

Comment: dob is defined as a string

Comment: you cannot do "std::string dod = ""; dob = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;", so it must be something else, you need to use sprinf( ... ) or a similar function.

Comment: I added sprinf( ... ) example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `#include <sstream>`, then set `dob` like this: `std::ostringstream oss; oss << mm << '/' << dd << '/' << yyyy; dob = oss.str();`.  If you want it to look better, google `std::setw` and `std::setfill` to pad out the day/month numbers to 2 digits.

You should also check for input errors:

```
if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &mm, &dd, &yyyy) != 3)
{
    std::cerr << "twit!  call that a date???\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

(As molbdnilo comments, your current problem is that you're adding extracting number from the parts of the date, then adding those numbers together along with the ASCII values of two '/' characters: instead you need to be concatenating string representations of those values, which a string stream is designed for.)

Comment: @aaaa: what private member?  `oss` can be a function-local / automatic variable; it's only class members like `dob` that can be private, protected or public, but clearly you want it set and to use it from other member functions.  The rest of your questions - I don't understand what you don't understand about how I've already suggested you do it....

Comment: At first I thought you were suggesting making my private member 'ostreamstring' type. I used your validation but I made a loop. Your answer was helpful. I went with the sprintf route though @Tony D